# SpringBoot: Jackson 2.9.7 -> Jackson 2.9.8+

Tags: spring-boot

The Spring Boot 2.1.1 managed version of Jackson is 2.9.7 which is superseded by Jackson 2.9.8. Our build is reporting exploitable vulnerabilities related to the older Jackson version.

If this point change in the managed dependency version cannot be accommodated promptly by Spring, is there a property I can set to force the version bump in my `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and it is [even documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-customizing):

> To customize a managed version you set its corresponding property.

To customize Jackson, you can add the following to your build:

```
ext['jackson.version'] = '2.9.8'
```

Jackson 2.9.8 [has been upgraded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15504) and will be available as of `2.0.8.RELEASE` due next week.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie. I read the Issue you referenced. Will the change in Spring Boot 2.0.8 be merged up into Spring Boot 2.1.2 ?

Comment: All changes are merged forward of course. it will be in 2.0.8, 2.1.2 and 2.2.0.M1